# How can a Python program determine which core it is running on?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to debug a Python 3 program that uses the `multiprocessing` module.

I want to keep track of which cores (of a multi-core machine) are getting used and how.

**Q:** I am looking for a way for the Python code to determine which core is running it.

---

The closest I have found is to use the following:

```
multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0] - 1
```

Putting aside the fact that such code appears to be "going behind the API,"<sup>1</sup> as far as I can tell, the code that initializes the `_identity` attribute makes no reference to the underlying hardware<sup>2</sup>, which I think is unsatisfactory.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> For one thing, I can find no official documentation for the `_identity` attribute, as one would expect from the leading underscore in the name.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> More specifically, this code evaluates something like `next(_process_counter)`, where `_process_counter` is initially set to the value `itertools.count(1)`, and uses the the result as the basis for the `_identity` attribute's value.</sup>

Comment: Processes don't necessarily stay on the same core, unless you take special provisions to lock it to a specific core.

Comment: `_identity` is used internally (to python-multiprocessing) for resource tracking, and should not be used or relied upon by users. Its usage or existence is not guaranteed to remain the same, nor would there be any warning of its changing (within a bugfix version change for example). Python's standard naming convention is that names with a single leading underscore are private (though it is not strictly enforced like with some languages).

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly ever be useful information (unless you do pinning, in which case you don't need to query because you already forced a specific association). Timeslices are _tiny_; sampling which core something is on at a given moment doesn't tell you anything about where it'll be a few milliseconds later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it would sound like from OP's question, they may be trying to do sampling statistics on which processor is being scheduled, which could definitely be a valid question in various scenarios (is the process being allocated to perf or efficiency cores on a BIG little arch for example).

Comment: They'd be better off using OS facilities to track that from _outside_ the process itself. (In Linux, that information is probably exposed via eBPF; certainly, one can get `switch` events to see when one is being moved onto or off of a CPU that way). Sampling is inherently lower-quality data than one gets from tracing, and tracing a process from inside that same process is inherently messy if not outright unworkable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely going to be an OS-specific problem, but here's how to do it in Windows ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessornumberex)). As mentioned in the comments, the processor number will likely be changing all the time unless you specifically pin the task to a given core (outside the scope of this answer).

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

class PROCESSOR_NUMBER(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Group", wintypes.WORD),
                ("Number", wintypes.BYTE),
                ("Reserved", wintypes.BYTE)]

pn = PROCESSOR_NUMBER()

windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcessorNumberEx(byref(pn))

print(pn.Number)
```

**Edit:** for Ubuntu 20.04.5 (WSL)

```py
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
print(libc.sched_getcpu())
```